# Modeling some constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

We have two decision variables $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{0+}$ that is the main decision variable and $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1$ that is an auxiliary decision variable.

Now based on the nature of the problem we are studying, we know that
$$y = \frac{1}{x}, \\
x=0 \Leftrightarrow y=\emptyset, \\
x>0 \Leftrightarrow y\geqslant0.
$$
Now the challenge is how to formulate the dynamics of these two decision variables in the constraints of a mathematical program. We have $x$ in the denominator and since at optimality $x$ can actually be zero, this would create a problem. Obviously, we cannot write $xy=1$ because if the optimal solution is that $x=0$, the equality would be violated.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does $y=\emptyset$ mean?

Comment: In which context you  want to formulate such constraint?

Comment: @RobPratt if $x=0$, then $y$ is not defined for the system. So for example, let us consider a call center. Let $x$ be the number of agents within that center. Then if we define $y$ as the utilization of that call center (percentage of time that the call center is being utilized), then $y = \alpha / x$ where $\alpha$ is a constant (function of a stochastic service time). If we decide to use no agents from that call center ($x=0$), then utilization of that call center is not define. Does this make sense?

Comment: @callculus In a queueing system where the number of servers is a primary decision variable and utilization becomes an auxiliary decision variable. But if you have other examples, I'd be thankful to know about them.

Comment: Where is $y$ used in the model?

Comment: @RobPratt only in the constraints and not in the objective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have an *a priori* upper bound $M$ (integer) on $x$. Introduce binary variables $z_0, z_1, \dots, z_M$, where $z_j=1$ if and only if $x=j$. Add the constraint $$x=\sum_{j=0}^M j*z_j$$ to define $x$ in terms of the new variables, and the constraint $$\sum_{j=0}^M z_j=1$$ to ensure that $x$ is uniquely determined. Finally, add the constraint $$y=\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{1}{j}*z_j$$to define $y$. Note that $x=0$ implies $y=0$ here.

There is no way to formulate a proper optimization model so as to make a variable "undefined" under certain circumstances. If letting $y=0$ when $x=0$ causes problems elsewhere in the model, you need to determine a numerical value for $y$ that can function as "undefined" in the remaining constraints.